# pyside6 comunication between mainwindow and widget

Tags: pyside6

I have 2 files (main, widget1), what i need is to be able to communicate between the 2.

edit:
sorry for the mess, i´ll try to put cleaner code.

So I have a main file with a stackedWidget(with Qt designer generated Ui file)and a widget file (also with qt generated Ui file) .
What i need is to be able to access the main file from the widget so i can change page of stackedWidget.

main.py:

```
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.widget1 = W1.Widget1(self)
        self.ui.stackedWidget_1.insertWidget(0, self.widget1)
        self.ui.stackedWidget_1.setCurrentIndex(0)

        def nextpage():
            self.ui.stackedWidget_1.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.ui.b0.clicked.connect(nextpage)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

widget.py

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from ui_widget import Ui_W1
import main
class Widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_W1()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        def widget_next_page():
            main.MainWindow().ui.stackedWidget_1.setCurrentIndex(0)
            print('0')

        self.ui.widget_button.clicked.connect(widget_next_page)
```

Thanks for any help, i´m trying to understand how to break the code into files so the main file don't get huge...
If there is any better way(not too complicated, cause as you surely know  already I'm starting.)

Comment: in `stacked_change` you're creating a *new* instance of MainWindow. You need to properly use signals and slot, but unfortunately we cannot help you more as your code has serious indentation and syntax problems and it's also not clear to what file each code block belongs to. Please ensure that you provide a valid [mre] and always check that you're properly [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) by checking the post preview before submitting the modifications.

Comment: I've corrected the code can you please take a look and give me an idea on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `widget_next_page` you're creating a *new* instance of `MainWindow`, instead of using the existing one.

The whole concept behind OOP modularity and Qt signals/slots is that an object should just emit a signal and not take actions on other objects on its own, especially if they are outside of its scope.

In your case, the `Widget1` should not try to change the page of its parent (the stacked widget of the main window).

Instead, the function changing the stacked widget index should be in the main window, and that function should be connected to whatever signal it should react to. Since you already have that function (`nextpage`), you can reuse it.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.widget1.ui.widget_button.clicked.connect(nextpage)
```

The above also means that you should remove the signal connection of the `widget_button` inside the `__init__` of `Widget1`.

<sup>Note that local functions should be used only when necessary, especially when connected to signals, otherwise it will be it very difficult to disconnect the specific function in case of need, since the reference is then lost when the outer function returns. Besides that, I strongly suggest you to do more research about how objects (specifically classes and instances) work in OOP in general and with Python.</sup>

Comment: so if i understand correctly i was look at this on the wrong side i tried to make a connection from widget to mainpage and it should be done from mainpage to widget. Thanks i am gonna do a lot of research on classes and instances, cause i just love working on python.

Comment: @LcrossPortugal your problem was not that the connection was done "in the wrong direction", but you were calling the function for the wrong object (a new instance of `MainWindow`). But, yes, you should normally do that by respecting the hierarchy, as the object that emits the signal should not be directly responsible of doing the expected result if that has effect on a different hierarchy level; when you press a button on an elevator, it is not that button that activates the elevator engine: it sends a "signal" to the control unit which then starts the engine and decides when it will stop.